# Cells containing number that is equal or greater than

Tags: vba, excel

what I am currently trying to do is to find and highlight cells that contain simultaneously a certain phrase and (among some other text) a number that is equal or greater than 20 (including numbers with decimals like 25.8332). I tried using FormatConditions, but I wasn't able to make it consider two simultaneous conditions (a phrase and a number). So I decided to use a combination of If and InStr, but I wonder how to fill in the **number that is equal or greater than 20**?

Comment: What do you mean by `how to fill in the number that is equal or greater than 20`? Also could you show us the contents of the cells in question?

Comment: For example, i want to make bold all cells that contain word "text" and any number that is equal or greater than 20. So Cell "Some text is 25" shall become bold. I came up only with this so far     If InStr(1, Cells(5, 7), "text") And InStr(1, Cells(5, 7), "i dont now how to write in a number that is equal or greater than 20") > 0 Then Cells(5, 6).Font.Bold = True .

Comment: Why not  use the built-in conditional formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the cells you wish to process and run:

```
Sub ColorMeYellow()
    Dim r As Range, s As String, n As Double
    Dim happy As String, CH As String, temp As String
    Dim L As Long, i As Long
    happy = "happy"

    For Each r In Selection
        s = r.Value
        If InStr(1, s, happy) > 0 Then
            L = Len(s)
            temp = ""
            For i = 1 To L
                CH = Mid(s, i, 1)
                If CH Like "[0-9]" Or CH = "." Then
                    temp = temp & CH
                End If
            Next i
            If IsNumeric(temp) Then
                If CDbl(temp) > 20 Then
                    r.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

It will look for cells containing both *"happy" and a number greater than 20.
[image]

Comment: @SviatLavrinchuk  Glad to help!